# How to solve singleton error while looping in odoo?

Tags: odoo, singleton-type

Kindly find the code given below which raises singleton error while executing and please let me know how to loop to select a particular record. Any help is appreciatable!

Code:

```
@api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        curr = datetime.now()
        new_date = datetime.strftime(curr, '%Y-%m-%d')
        cal_obj = self.env['daily.attendance'].search([])
        if cal_obj:
            for co in cal_obj:
                co.date
            if co.date == new_date:
                raise ValidationError(_('''Current Date Attendance Already Exist!'''))
        return super(DailyAttendance, self).create(vals)

    @api.onchange('user_id')
    def onchange_department(self):
        if self.user_id == True:
            emps = self.env['hr.employee'].search([])
            emp_attd = []
            from datetime import datetime

            now = datetime.now() # current date and time
            check_in = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            check_in_from = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 05:30')
            check_out = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            check_out_from = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 14:30')
            for emp in emps:
                vals = {
                    'employe_id':emp.id,
                    'check_in': check_in_from,
                    'check_out': check_out_from,
                    'is_present': True
```

Comment: What's the specific error text that you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid singleton error, kindly add loop for self as given below:

```
@api.onchange('user_id')
def onchange_department(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.user_id == True:
            emps = rec.env['hr.employee'].search([])
            emp_attd = []
            from datetime import datetime

            now = datetime.now() # current date and time
            check_in = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            check_in_from = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 05:30')
            check_out = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            check_out_from = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 14:30')
            for emp in emps:
                vals = {
                    'employe_id':emp.id,
                    'check_in': check_in_from,
                    'check_out': check_out_from,
                    'is_present': True
```

Comment: Dear Sake I tried this way and still the problem is not solved........ I updated the code with full code if it might locate some clue...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
NameError: name 'rec' is not defined